# How to disable IE8 script error message?

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, coded-ui-tests

I'm using CodedUI on IE8, and get this error message:

```
     Stop running this script?
     A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly.
     If it continues to run, your computer might become unresponsive.
```

I've read some forums and did the following: Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab > Browsing

1. Check the "Disable script debugging (Internet Explorer) checkbox
2. Check the "Disable script debugging (Other) checkbox
3. Uncheck the "Display a notification about every script error" checkbox

and this message still appears...

Can anyone assist me here?

Answer (score 8):

IE has a registry setting for that

[Error message: "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175500/en-us)

but that requires you so change the registry on each client machine and for each user.

It will however allow you script to run so you can profile it and find out whats causing the delay.

Also look at this SO question [How to mimic effects of MaxScriptStatements (i.e. prevent “A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly”) without changing the registry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236319/how-to-mimic-effects-of-maxscriptstatements-i-e-prevent-a-script-on-this-page)